# my console.log does not work in my html page

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to javascript but I can't go forward in learning because my console.log doesn't work AT ALL I will type in the console.log message and on my html page nothing shows up. i have try to debug it but I'm so new I don't know how all I can do is go to the forums and ask, it seem some people have the problem but, there is no good answer to the problem. I've tried every thing i know how to do (which isn't very much) but nothing works PLEASE HELP!!

this is my program

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My First proper HTML page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>My First web page.</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("Hello World!"</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i know that it has to be in dev tool to see it now but how do i make it show up in the html not in dev.?
there has to be a way!
i now now that document.write is the right way but that isn't working either

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My First proper HTML page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>My First web page.</p>
    <script>
    var name = "Nicholas";
    document.write("Hello " + name);
    if (name.length > 7 {
    document.write("Wow you have a Really Long name!");
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is `control.log`? do you mean `console.log` ?

Comment: yes console.log sry i told you I'm new

Comment: i know that its console .log i just got confused in the question i did type in console.log in the program

Comment: in my book it show the right way to write it and I've written it exactly  like in the book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, console.log is not supposed to show up on your HTML page. Rather, it shows up on your console's (web browser) log.

Even with all the correct answers provided, you can view your answer by visiting the Developer Tool -> Console (For Chrome, on Apple, it's Option + Command + J). For Windows, using Chrome, you hold the following keys: Ctrl+Shift+J

Here is a clip of the code and the log recorded by the console:

[image]

Comment: @OreDroids It showed up twice because I refreshed a few times. In regards to pasting it to HTML, you need to use document.write("SOMETHING"). You can see my sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/kob7av77/

Comment: To better explain document.write(x) = document is your page (for this case, your HTML page), and write explains itself. So, wherever you place this Javascript code, the JS compiler will 'write' on the document the argument (for this case, 'x') you provided

Comment: But why would my book show console.log in the first place?

Comment: @OreDroids Most welcome! If you need more help with the basics, I recommend looking into codeacademy which offers quick tutorials on Javascript: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript - It's VERY VERY good for beginners and I highly recommend it!

Comment: @OreDroids the purpose of console.log() is to provide you with information that is primarily viewed by the developer. It's a clean way to test your code instead of seeing random stuff on your HTML page. You'll be using it more extensively when you will be working on testing your JavaScript code :D

Comment: @OreDroids go through codeacademy link I provided. It'll explain why some things won't work and give basic bug testing. Right now, it's hard to know what's wrong without looking the code :)

Comment: The problem is that I have already gotten far in my book and I really don't want to have to start over with code Academy

Comment: i have looked in the code academy and it doesn't explain anything about document.write it just says to write console.log

Comment: @OreDroids can you paste your code on http://jsfiddle.net/, 'Save' your code, and then share the URL

Answer (score 1):

because you have to type console.log()

not control.log

Also, console.log needs to be either inside script tags, or in a separate javascript file. In your case you would have to do:

console.log("Hello, World!");

Answer (score 0):

Try the below sample

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("Hello World")
</script>
</head>
<body>
Hello
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried copy and pasting what you wrote into brackets and only the hello showed up

Comment: Hello world will be shon in console. open development tool and see it in console tab

Answer (score 0):

Unless you typed/edited your post.. that has an invalid Javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My First proper HTML page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
   <p>My First web page.</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("Hello World!");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You did not have a closing )

Ah, as others have explained.. Console is not your HTML page, its part of the web browser itself. For example, in google chrome press CTRL+SHIFT+J to show it.

Your after document.write